# Permalink Linking Issues (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

My current blog is www.bostonsbettah.com and my current permalink set-up is http://www.bostonsbettah.com/%category%/%postname%/

Now, in a perfect world, the a post should appear as something like www.bostonsbettah.com/bostonbruins/boston-bruins-1st-line-playing-like-a-1st-line/ and that should take you to the post. When I click on the page title at the top such as "Bruins Blog", it should take me to www.bostonsbettah.com/bostonbruins/ that has an archive of all posts categorized as "Bruins". Currently, however, every page besides the home page is a 404 error.

Now I know I can fix something in the .htaccess file and I know how to access it, but I don't want to mess with it as I don't know how to code. Is there a fix someone can provide that will allow me to fix my website? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting your permalinks to standard and back to what you had? Does that fix the issue?

Comment: It does, but then they are ugly permalinks such as "?cat=5" or something like that.

Comment: Have you tried postname? or custom?

Answer (score 0):

Never,ever,ever put **your blog URL** inside custom permalink structure!. You must use one of the structure tags, or a combination of tags only.

Read the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) first.

Comment: I didn't, I was just showing what the URL would look like. The custom is just /%category%/%postname%/